# How to work with Vmod Xkey to invalidate object in cache

Tags: varnish, cache-control, varnish-vcl

I'm using xKey Vmode plugin to purge objects through tags. I did set up my varnish configuration to work and support xkey but now I didn't find any resource on how to send that data through varnishadm or vcl. currently, I'm using HTTP ban

```
curl -X BAN -H 'X-Purge-Regex: 1.pbf' varnish
```

to invalidate with BAN.

Also is that possible to send xkey value with commoa seperated?
like: my cached URL is something like:

1. [www.example.com/foo/xyz?name="t1;t2"](http://www.example.com/foo/xyz?name=%22t1;t2%22)
2. [www.example.com/foo/abc?name="t1](http://www.example.com/foo/abc?name=%22t1)
3. [www.example.com/foo/xyz?name="t2"](http://www.example.com/foo/xyz?name=%22t2%22)

Currently, with BAN URL - i pass t1 value with regex and that is able to invalidate #1 and #2,
but now with Xkey

1. How to send http with xkey?
2. Is there a way Xkey supports multiple tags in a single request?
3. Can I send xkey with (xyz, t2) - With this, I want to invalidate #1 and #2.

Answer (score 3):

### Install vmod_xkey

In order to use `vmod_xkey`, you need to install it by compiling https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules from source. Please make sure you select the right branch in GitHub, based on the Varnish version you use.

### The xkey API

`vmod_xkey` has 2 functions:

- `xkey.purge()`, which will immediately remove content from cache
- `xkey.softpurge()`, which will mark content as expired, but keeps it around for asynchronous revalidation

### The VCL code

Here's the VCL code you can use to invalidate content using tags:

```
vcl 4.1;

import xkey;
import std;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405));
        }
        if(!req.http.x-xkey-purge) {
            return(synth(400,"x-xkey-purge header missing"));
        }

        set req.http.x-purges = xkey.purge(req.http.x-xkey-purge);

        if (std.integer(req.http.x-purges,0) != 0) {
             return(synth(200, req.http.x-purges + " objects purged"));
        } else {
            return(synth(404, "Key not found"));
        }
    }
}
```

> Please ensure `acl purge` contains the right IP addresses or IP ranges prior to using this.

By adding `import xkey;` to the VCL file, secondary keys are automatically registered in Varnish, and can be used later on.

The `PURGE` request method is used to trigger `xkey.purge()` and the `x-xkey-purge` request header is used to specify the tags.

### Registering keys

Registering keys happens by specifying them in the `Xkey` response header. You can register a single key, but you can also add multiple ones.

Multiple keys are separated by *space or comma*.

Here's an example where 3 keys are registered:

- `category_sports`
- `id_1265778`
- `type_article`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=60
Xkey: category_sports id_1265778 type_article
```

### Removing content based on keys

By performing a `PURGE` call and by specifying the right `X-Xkey-Purge` value, content will be removed for these keys.

Here's an example where we remove all objects matching the `category_sports` tag for all pages on the `http://example.com` website:

```
PURGE / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-Xkey-Purge: category_sports
```

Here's another example where we invalidate content that matches the `foo` and `bar` keys:

```
PURGE / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-Xkey-Purge: foo bar
```